# How to put a Textbox into a DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

For whatever reason the textbox's value does not change when the underlying data does.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
    OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                PopulateOPCodes();
            }
            RefreshData(DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void PopulateOPCodes()
    {
        var dataReader = new OdbcCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(OP_CD) FROM LDL_FOREMAN", dbConnection).ExecuteReader();                
        while (dataReader.Read()) DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dataReader[0].ToString()));                
        dbConnection.Close();
    }

    protected void RefreshData(string OpCode)
    {
        //var dbCommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM LDL_FOREMAN WHERE OP_CD = '" + OpCode + "'", dbConnection);

        var dbCommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM LDL_FOREMAN WHERE OP_CD = ?", dbConnection);
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("OP_CD", OpCode);


        var dataset = new DataSet();
        var dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(dbCommand);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);

        GridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 5)
        {
            e.Row.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Linen");
            var textBox = new TextBox {Text = e.Row.Cells[1].Text};
            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(textBox);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Inserts inevitable comment about parameterizing queries to prevent sql injection*.

Comment: Is that he only way I can get an answer from you?

Comment: @NicholasV. Added Parameterizing.. please answer my question. ;)

Comment: Ha, nope. It was kind of a little joke, every time there is a question where someone is concatenating their sql queries, someone always informs them of sql inject (*not a bad thing to mention, it's just so pervasive I think everyone is aware by now ...*). It's almost like SO should magically detect this to warn the user :-P. Sorry if I came off as rude